# I am stuck with MVC pattern

Tags: java, model-view-controller, netbeans, controller, fxml

Recently, I am working on a java application based on MVC pattern. There is a table that I am going to insert some elements into it. And When I use the setItems() function to link the table to the model. This function does not work. I already check whether the way of linking an fxml file to the relevant controller is correct or not. It has no problems. However, When I run this project and click on the view catalogue button. Netbeans returns this error "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException". Therefore, I failed to insert elements into the table. Please, help me figure out what is going on. Many thanks. Others files do not have any problems because I have checked.

```css
Executing F:\UTS\Third Semester\Application programming\Java Slef-study\JavaFx self-StudyDe\48024 SPR 2019 Assignment 2 Skeleton (NETBEANS)\dist\run995722807\48024 SPR 2018 Assignment 2 Skeleton (NETBEANS).jar using platform D:\NetBean\jre/bin/java
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
 at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
 at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
 at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
 at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
 at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
 ... 48 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/F:/UTS/Third%20Semester/Application%20programming/Java%20Slef-study/JavaFx%20self-StudyDe/48024%20SPR%202019%20Assignment%202%20Skeleton%20(NETBEANS)/dist/run995722807/48024%20SPR%202018%20Assignment%202%20Skeleton%20(NETBEANS).jar!/view/catalogue.fxml

 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
 at au.edu.uts.ap.javafx.ViewLoader.showStage(ViewLoader.java:20)
 at controller.ComputerBuilderController.handleViewCatalogue(ComputerBuilderController.java:23)
 ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
 ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: model.ComputerBuilder cannot be cast to model.Catalogue
 at controller.CatalogueController.getCatalogue(CatalogueController.java:44)
 at controller.CatalogueController.initialize(CatalogueController.java:31)
 ... 72 more
```

### Catalogue.java(Model)

```js
package model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Catalogue {

 private ObservableList<Part> parts;
 private ObservableList<Part> currentView;
 private final Build build;

 public Catalogue(Build build) {

  this.build = build;

  parts = FXCollections.<Part>observableArrayList();
  currentView = FXCollections.<Part>observableArrayList();

  parts.add(new Part("evo 860", "storage", 155.00));
  parts.add(new Part("daskeyboard", "keyboard", 239.00));
  parts.add(new Part("i5", "cpu", 365.00));
  parts.add(new Part("corsair 16G", "memory", 299.00));
  parts.add(new Part("ASUS ROG", "motherboard", 159.00));
  parts.add(new Part("sheetmetal box", "case", 39.00));
  parts.add(new Part("Ryzen 7", "cpu", 299.00));

  currentView.addAll(parts);
  parts.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Part>() {
   @Override
   public void onChanged(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Part> c) {
    currentView.clear();
    currentView.addAll(parts);
   }

  });
 }

 public void addPart(String name, String type, double price) {
  parts.add(new Part(name, type, price));
 }

 public ObservableList<Part> getCurrentView() {
  return currentView;
 }

 public void filterList(String type, String min, String max) {

  List<Part> temp = new ArrayList<Part>();

  for (Part p : parts) {
   try {
    if ((type.equals("") || p.hasType(type)) && (min.equals("") || p.costsAtLeast(Double.parseDouble(min)))
      && (max.equals("") || p.costsAtMost(Double.parseDouble(max)))) {
     temp.add(p);
    }
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   }
  }

  this.currentView.clear();
  this.currentView.addAll(temp);
 }

 public void addToBuild(Part p) {
  build.addPart(p);
 }

 public void addToBuild(List<Part> selectedItems) {
  build.addParts(selectedItems);
 }

 public void remove(Part p) {
  parts.remove(p);
 }

 public void remove(List<Part> selectedItems) {
  parts.removeAll(selectedItems);
 }

}
```

### Catalogue.fxml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" 
      fx:controller="controller.CatalogueController" alignment="TOP_LEFT" spacing="10"  >
    
    <TableView fx:id="CatalogueTb" prefWidth="600" prefHeight="400" >
        <placeholder><Label text="No parts in current build." /></placeholder>
        <columns>
            <TableColumn text="Type" fx:id="typeClm"></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn text="Name" fx:id="nameClm"></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn text="Price" fx:id="priceClm"></TableColumn>
        </columns>
    </TableView>
    
    <GridPane alignment="TOP_LEFT" hgap="10" vgap="10">
        <Text text="Filters" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2"/>
        <Label text="Type:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
        <TextField fx:id="typeTf" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
        <Label text="Price Range:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
        <TextField fx:id="PriceRangeTf" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    </GridPane>
            <Button text="Add Selected to Build" fx:id="AddSelectedBtn"/>
            <Button text="Add New Part to Catalogue"  fx:id="AddNewBtn"/>
            <Button text="Remove Selected from Catalogue" fx:id="RemoveSelectedBtn"/>
            <Button text="Close" fx:id="CloseBtn" onAction="#handleClose"/>
</VBox>
```

### CatalogueController.java

```js
package controller;

import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.beans.binding.*;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import model.*;
import au.edu.uts.ap.javafx.*;

public class CatalogueController extends Controller<Catalogue>{

    @FXML private TableView<Part> CatalogueTb;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Part, String> typeClm;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Part, String> nameClm;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Part, String> priceClm;
    
    @FXML private TextField typeTf;
    @FXML private TextField PriceRangeTf;
    
    @FXML private Button AddSelectedBtn;
    @FXML private Button RemoveSelectedBtn;
        
    @FXML private void initialize() {
        
        CatalogueTb.setItems(model.getCurrentView());
        AddSelectedBtn.setDisable(true);
        RemoveSelectedBtn.setDisable(true);
        
        typeClm.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().typeProperty());
        nameClm.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
        priceClm.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().priceProperty().asString("$%.2f"));
        
        CatalogueTb.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
             (observable, oldSubject, newSubject) -> AddSelectedBtn.setDisable(newSubject == null));
             
    }
```

Comment: Please provide us with the **complete** error trace if any.

Comment: Ok, I added the rest of error trace.

Comment: Here we go, actual exception is ClassCastException computerBuilder cannot cast to Catalogue. Please check your Catalogue.fxml stylesheets's URL - you're invoking @computerbuilder.css. is that accurate? Otherwise, provide me the **complete** Catalogue.fxml file

Comment: For quick and efficient help post [mre], post the entire stacktrace (as text) and mark the line that throws the exception (CatalogueController.java line 44) with a comment.
Please folloe [java naming conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/)

Comment: It is accurate. Ok I am now providing the complete Catalogue.fxml file.

Comment: Please provide the implementation of  getCatalogue() method as well - it looks like the error reside at Controller.java where the casting exception occurs.

Comment: I directly deleted getCatalogue() method, instead, I am now using model. Like CatalogueTb.setItems(model.getCurrentView()); becasue using getCatalogue() method will cause error. But after I used model, netbeans still displays the error.